# Selecting images in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a grid of images which is echoed out as HTML from a PHP function. The images currently have an onclick() function which adds a value linked to the image to a universal value. EG: `universalInt += imageInt;`

What I want to do is, when the image is clicked, have some kind of variable show that the image is selected, and when it is clicked again it is unselected. I want this so the onclick() function can work like this:

```
    if(selected){ 
    universalInt += imageInt;
    //append item to array
} 
    else if (!selected){ 
    universalInt -= imageInt; 
    //remove item from array
}
```

I've been looking around but I can't find anything, is there a simple way to add a "selected"-like variable to a HTML image? I would prefer not to use an add-on.

Comment: You can give the selected images a `data-selected` attribute or whatever. That way, you can also easily give selected images different visual styles through CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
function select(opts) {

  // caching the clicked element for later (repeated) use:    
  var clicked = this,

  // setting the default settings:
    defaults = {
      'element': 'img',
      'selectedAttribute': 'data-selected',
      'markParent': true,
      'parentAttribute': 'data-childSelected',
      'parentMarker': '✓'
    };

  // finding the currently-selected elements (if any) and, if
  // any are found, converting that NodeList to an Array,
  // otherwise using an empty array:    
  var selected = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']'), 0).length ? Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']'), 0) : [];

  // discovering whether the clicked element is already
  // in the array (if it's already selected):
  isSelected = selected.indexOf(clicked) > -1;

  // if it's in the array already, we want to de-select:
  if (isSelected) {

    // we de-select by removing the relevant attribute:
    clicked.removeAttribute(defaults.selectedAttribute);

    // if the settings indicate that the parent is also
    // marked:
    if (defaults.markParent === true) {

      // we remove the parent's 'marking' attribute also:
      clicked.parentNode.removeAttribute(defaults.parentAttribute);
    }
  } else {

    // otherwise we set the 'marking' attribute on the 
    // clicked element (to true), and:
    clicked.setAttribute(defaults.selectedAttribute, true);

    // if we're to mark the parent also:
    if (defaults.markParent === true) {

      // we set the parent-marking attribute to the string
      // held in the given variable, for use in the CSS (later):
      clicked.parentNode.setAttribute(defaults.parentAttribute, defaults.parentMarker);
    }
  }

  // here we return the (new) NodeList of selected elements:
  return document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']');
}

// converting the NodeList of <img> elements to an array:    
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), 0);

// iterating over that array with Array.prototype.forEach(),
// the first argument to forEach() (here: 'img') is the
// current array-element of the array over we're iterating:
images.forEach(function(img) {

  // binding the select() function to handle the 'click' event
  // on the given element-node:
  img.addEventListener('click', select);
});
```

```js
function select(opts) {

  var clicked = this,
    defaults = {
      'element': 'img',
      'selectedAttribute': 'data-selected',
      'markParent': true,
      'parentAttribute': 'data-childSelected',
      'parentMarker': '✓'
    };

  var selected = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']'), 0).length ? Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']'), 0) : [];
  isSelected = selected.indexOf(clicked) > -1;

  if (isSelected) {
    clicked.removeAttribute(defaults.selectedAttribute);
    if (defaults.markParent === true) {
      clicked.parentNode.removeAttribute(defaults.parentAttribute);
    }
  } else {
    clicked.setAttribute(defaults.selectedAttribute, true);
    if (defaults.markParent === true) {
      clicked.parentNode.setAttribute(defaults.parentAttribute, defaults.parentMarker);
    }
  }

  return document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']');
}

var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), 0);

images.forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('click', select);
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
li[data-childSelected]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 190, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
li[data-childSelected]::after {
  content: attr(data-childSelected);
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 190, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#selected::before {
  content: 'Selected images: '
}
#selected:empty::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="selected"></div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/5" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/6" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/7" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/8" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hgyhgy9x/), for experimentation.

Alternatively, to use the returned NodeList we can call the exact same function in the following way (the unchanged function omitted here for brevity, but it's in the Snippet and external Fiddle):

```
images.forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // setting the textContent of the selected Node
    // to the length of the returned NodeList:
    document.getElementById('selected').textContent = select.apply(img).length;
    // above we use Function.prototype.apply() to
    // explicitly set the select() function's 'this'
  });
});
```

```js
function select(opts) {

  var clicked = this,
    defaults = {
      'element': 'img',
      'selectedAttribute': 'data-selected',
      'markParent': true,
      'parentAttribute': 'data-childSelected',
      'parentMarker': '✓'
    };

  var selected = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']'), 0).length ? Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']'), 0) : [];
  isSelected = selected.indexOf(clicked) > -1;

  if (isSelected) {
    clicked.removeAttribute(defaults.selectedAttribute);
    if (defaults.markParent === true) {
      clicked.parentNode.removeAttribute(defaults.parentAttribute);
    }
  } else {
    clicked.setAttribute(defaults.selectedAttribute, true);
    if (defaults.markParent === true) {
      clicked.parentNode.setAttribute(defaults.parentAttribute, defaults.parentMarker);
    }
  }

  return document.querySelectorAll(defaults.element + '[' + defaults.selectedAttribute + ']');
}

var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), 0);

images.forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('selected').textContent = select.apply(img).length;
  });
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
li[data-childSelected]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 190, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
li[data-childSelected]::after {
  content: attr(data-childSelected);
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 190, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#selected::before {
  content: 'Selected images: '
}
#selected:empty::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="selected"></div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/5" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/6" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/7" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/8" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hgyhgy9x/1/), for experimentation.

References:

- CSS:

  - CSS "[Generated content, automatic numbering and lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html)."
  - [CSS pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements).
  - [`:empty`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo).
  - [`pointer-events`](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [Conditional/ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
  - [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).
  - [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: I'm sorry somebody gave you a down-vote because wow, you have obviously put a lot of effort into this answer. This, and the examples is exactly what I needed, I'm really grateful for the help. Though I have to say, all of this is not my strong-suite and I find the more complex stuff a little harder to follow. This being said, I've implemented this into my code, but it's changed the layout somewhat of my page, and the images don't get highlighted like in the example. I already have ul li styles, but none of the titles are exactly the same as what is in the (second) CSS code you posted. Cont..

Comment: I already layout my grid of images I am clicking by using <li> </li>, should this effect how this works? Basically, using the second example, I have copied the CSS and JavaScript into my code, leaving my HTML to print out the images as <li> </li> like they already were. I'm sorry if I sound a bit silly, I assume my current CSS is affecting it?

Comment: The only parts of the CSS that matters, really, is the `li::before` and `li::after`, and those can be entirely re-styled as you wish; all the rest is purely incidental and only there to give a (relatively) pleasing look. Oh, as to the down-vote, it doesn't matter particularly, it's just that if there's a problem with my answer I'd like to know about it in order to improve it.

Comment: Oh, and the `position` property for the `li` must be set to any (valid) value other than `static` (the default), in order to use `position: absolute` on the generated content. But all the rest can still be altered or adjusted to your taste.

Comment: I have an image which sits over the current image, which I plan on toggling according to whether the image is clicked, and the current effects don't seem to work anyway with my layout. I don't think I need the position if I get rid of all the added style? I don't want to ask you to do to much, but could you possible update your answer with a section of the code with all the parts that add the style removed? I think I have done it myself, but I feel like I may leave some in or take some out that I need.

Comment: I'm sorry for bugging you mate, you are a great help though. One last question, how can I access the list of items selected? What line of code or variable should I use from the JavaScript function?

Comment: The part that "*adds the style*" is setting the various attributes. If you don't want the styles just remove the CSS, and replace with your own. You can set `'markParent' : false` to avoid setting the attribute to the parent (if you wish)? But selecting/deselecting is based upon the `data-selected` attribute being set on the `<img>` elements. Can you post an *absolutely minimal* demo on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and I'll take a look - but I don't have time to dig through anything complex, so: ***minimal***, and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I have it all worked out now. My only problem is using the list of items. I can see where and how it is returning to say "selected images: 1", I can't use that anywhere else though. Trying to set that line as a variable then update HTML with it by using _document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = var_ I get an error. I just need to know how to use this as a variable, and how to access the array of items, and I'll be all set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78700/discussion-between-david-thomas-and-mitchcool1).

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick callback you can do something like this

```
function onCLickCallback() {
    if(selected){
      selected = false;
    }
    else {
      selected = true;
    }

    if(selected){ 
        universalInt += imageInt;
        //append item to array
    } 
        else if (!selected){ 
        universalInt -= imageInt; 
        //remove item from array
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second block of code needs a trigger without which this solution pretty much falls back to the same dilemma that OP has.

Comment: @EnKrypt I have edited my answer. I think earlier I was not clear enough. The whole code goes within the callback function. So on every click selected's value would be toggled and according to the toggled value imageInt would be calculated.

Comment: 'Selected' would have to be defined somewhere first as false though. I'm not sure where to do that. You can't define it on the call because it will always be the same.

Comment: Yes, I agree. You can make it a global variable but that won't be a good practice as you should avoid cluttering the global scope. You can add it to one of the parent scopes, but to tell the exact place I would need to see more of your code.

Comment: @ankur I wouldn't be able to add a global variable anyway, because the images are generated systematically, there will be a different number of 'Selected' variables each time the page is loaded. I need a way to have the variable created with the image.

Comment: @ankur Any more ideas on how I could achieve this?